# ¿Buscar con input y mostrar filas automaticas de una tabla? LARAVEL

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, laravel

Buenas que tal esta es una consulta que tengo, He visto varios tutoriales sobre como hacer una busqueda con input text, y al escribir un dato se cargan automaticamente las filas de una tabla pero siempre en "php,mysql,jquery,ajax" pero con Laravel? Se puede? Alguien me podria ayudar por favor?
Este es mi linea de codigo del cargado de la tabla normal y el input que quisiera que haga el cargado

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInputCodigo">Codigo</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_codigo" id="formGroupExampleInputCodigo">
 </div>

<div class="row" style="height:300px; overflow:auto;">
     <table class="table">
         <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center" colspan="5">Lista de Establecimientos</th>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                     <th>Codigo</th>
                     <th>Nombre</th>
                     <th>Distrito</th>
                     <th>Provincia</th>
                     <th>Departamento</th>
              </tr>
       </thead>

              <tbody>
                     @foreach($establecimientos_listar as $el)
                     <tr>
                            <td>{{$el->CodigoEstablecimiento}}</td>
                            <td>{{$el->NombreEstablecimiento}}</td>
                            <td>{{$el->NombreDistrito}}</td>
                            <td>{{$el->NombreProvincia}}</td>
                            <td>{{$el->NombreDepartamento}}</td>
                     </tr>
                     @endforeach
              </tbody>

              </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Quieres hacer un consulta desde base de datos o quieres que simplemete se te filtren los datos?

Comment: @Elio Hola que tal amigo, si bueno quiero que sea con una base de datos pero nose exactamente como hacer que se haga el cargado con el input y la tabla (disculpa la demora)

Comment: En todo caso puedo desarrollarte un ejemplo como respuesta, depende de con que tecnología estés familiarizado, me indicas si conoces JS/JQUERY.

Comment: @Elio Si amigo, conozco jquery js, gracias por el ejemplo no importa si es simple, solo necesito saber como se hace. Gracias!

Comment: @Elio Hola que tal amigo, todo me sirvio de tu ejemplo pero ahora tengo 2 problemas: 1° Es que al momento de borrar por ejemplo el input lo que he escrito, la tabla sigue carga y no desaparece y el 2° Es que al momento de hacer una busqueda con el codigo, por ejemplo busco por el codigo '00001' y en vez que me cargue solo esa fila con ese codigo me cargan todos las filas que el codigo inicie en '0000'. Te ha pasado eso?

Comment: @Elio ya me salio, resulta que en la function del input con la id=search en vez de poner 'keypress' era 'keyup'

Comment: Y esto soluciono los 2 errores anteriores que tenia

Comment: Disculpa estuve por un tiempo afuera... Sino solucionaste tus problemas escribeme. Si en cuanto al evento puedes usar `keydown` o `keyup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno para poder hacer consultas con AJAX te dejo este pequeño ejemplo:

Tal vez por si te parezca más cómodo también podrías hacerlo con un botón.

```
<input id="search"> <button id="action-button"> BUSCAR </button>
```

Como te comente líneas arriba te dejo un ejemplo para los siguientes para los dos casos:

Búsqueda mientras el usuario va ingresando un texto.

```
 $("#search").on('keypress', function() {
        var myText = $(this).val();
     })
```

Al presionar el botón

```
$("#action-button").on('click', function() {
            var myText = $(this).val();
         })
```

Ahora vamos con el AJAX, el cual se encargará de hacer la petición para obtener la nueva información.

**NOTA: Ten en cuenta que este AJAX debe de ir en el evento que vayas a utilizar, lo separe solo por orden.**

```
$.ajax({
   url: "tu-ruta",
   type: "post",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}", text: myText },
   success: function (response) {
      $("#table-body").html(response);
   }
})
```

En tu controlador podrías tener algo como esto:

```
   my_function(Request $request)
   {
      $text = $request->text;
      // Haces tu consulta para eloquent en este caso para el ejemplo
      $data = Office::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$text.'%')->get();
      // resultados es una vista que crearas para reemplazar el contenido de tu tabla. 
      $view = view('resultados', compact('data'))->render();
      return response()->json($view);
   }
```

Y finalmente tu vista que se llamará `resultados.blade.php` con el contenido que vas a reemplazar en tu tabla, en este caso vamos a reemplazar el contenido del `<tbody>`.

```
@foreach($data as $el)
     <tr>
         <td>{{$el->CodigoEstablecimiento}}</td>
         <td>{{$el->NombreEstablecimiento}}</td>
         <td>{{$el->NombreDistrito}}</td>
         <td>{{$el->NombreProvincia}}</td>
         <td>{{$el->NombreDepartamento}}</td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

Espero te sea útil este ejemplo, cualquier duda me comentas.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! Me sirvio, muy claro tu ejemplo! Y por supuesto esta correcto :D (y) (Disculpa por la demora)

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias por ejemplo, he probado y hace el envio de los datos pero no logro hacer que me de respuesta a la busqueda podrias ayudarme con este, en el ejemplo me da este error en la vista ErrorException
Undefined variable: data (View:

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/326357)